# I get "Possible null reference return" warning, although result is declared maybe null

Tags: c#, null

I am new to C#. I do not get why I still get this warning when I have marked the return type with "?". See screen shot attached.

```
    public Item? GetItem(Guid id)
    {
        return items.Where(item => item.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

[Code and warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM9wn.png)

Comment: So it seems that `Item` is a class and you have [nullable reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) checks enabled (`#nullable enable` or the equivalent setting in the project file)? Which Compiler or VisualStudio version do you use?

Comment: As a side note, you can simplify the LINQ expression as `items.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);`

Comment: Where did you get `items`?

Answer (score 0):

Item is a class, which can be null so you don't need to put nullbale keyword ? in that. May that is why you are getting warning.
If you put nullable with non-nullable data type like int, you will not get that warning.

Comment: _"Any variable where the ? isn't appended to the type name is a non-nullable reference type. That includes all reference type variables in existing code when you've enabled this feature."_ ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references))

Answer (score 0):

1. `Item` is a reference type, which are nullable, so you do not need to append a `?` to the typename.
2. The warning is `possible null reference return`. Marking a type as nullable does not remove the possibility of a null reference return. The return value is thus marked by the compiler as maybe-null. This is why you get the warning.

To resolve the warning, remove the nullable operator `?` and if the warning persists, implement a null check into to the function.

Comment: _"Any variable where the ? isn't appended to the type name is a non-nullable reference type. That includes all reference type variables in existing code when you've enabled this feature."_ ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references))  - this makes it sound like you need the `?` if you wish to return `null`

Comment: @Llama *"Null-state analysis and variable annotations are disabled by default for existing projects—meaning that all reference types continue to be nullable. Starting in .NET 6, they're enabled by default for new projects."* (from your source) - this makes it sound like your quote is out of context.